# from video to canvas to image

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

i have been looking for a straight answer without making a new question, trying to figure it out with other approach but doesn't seem to be like it.

I have this form to upload videos into my webpage (why? good question, because i like to complicate my life as much as i can). And in this form when you chose the video it automatically show on the canvas a little image in the first quarter of the video (why again?? don't know just seems like a good time) and when i try to take that generated image of the canvas to url data and put that same url data to an input field to upload it with the form i get this error:

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('fotodemourl').value = img')

now, i kind of know what the error means, but not why is generated, i leave my code below, can anybody tell my how to get the url data to the input??

```
    <label>Video:</label>
    <input type="file" name="vid" id="vid">
    <label>Duración:</label>
    <input type="text" name="viddur" id="viddur" size="6">
    <label style="color:grey;"><i>min:sec</i></label>

    <label>Foto:</label>
    <canvas id="fotodemo" style="width:150px; height:100px;"></canvas>
    <input type="text" name="fotodemourl">
    <input type="submit" value="Subir">

    </form>

    <video id="video" style="display:none;"></video>
    <script>
        var dur = 0;
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(e){
            dur = Math.round(e.currentTarget.duration);
            var min = Math.floor(dur / 60);
            var sec = dur % 60;



            document.getElementById('viddur').value = min + ':' + sec;

            var canvas = document.getElementById('fotodemo')
            var imgt = Math.floor(dur/4);
            video.currentTime = imgt;
            var vwidth = video.videoWidth;
            var vheight = video.videoHeight;
            var widthp = (canvas.width / vwidth);
            var heightp = (canvas.height / vheight);
            var prop = Math.min(widthp, heightp);
            var centx = (canvas.width - vwidth*prop)/2;
            var centy = (canvas.height - vheight*prop)/2;
            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, centx, centy, vwidth*prop, vheight*prop);
            var canvasimg = canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, centx, centy, vwidth*prop, vheight*prop);
            var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            document.getElementById('fotodemourl').value = img;

            URL.revokeObjectURL(obUrl);
        });
        var obUrl;
        document.getElementById('vid').addEventListener('change', function(e){
            var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
            if(file.name.match(/\.(mp4)$/i)){
                obUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                document.getElementById('video').setAttribute('src', obUrl);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have any element with '`fotodemourl`' id,
Add id to your HTML element.

```
<input type="text" name="fotodemourl" id="fotodemourl">
```

Comment: how stupid me, with some much coding in other parts i just didn't see it, thanks a lot, how dumb i feel right now